# VS/C# Autogenerate Named Arguments when calling a method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Visual Studio (C#) has the concept of [Named Arguments](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/optional-parameters-and-named-arguments-in-c-4-and-a-cool-scenario-w-asp-net-mvc-2). Is there a way, without a 3rd party plug-in to auto-generate the parameter list when calling the method? (I'm looking to save a bunch of typing by having the list of **param: [value], //type** auto-generated via a keyboard shortcut/chord.) This would be akin to what the SSMS / RedGate intellisense does.

For example in SSMS:

```
EXEC dbo.ContactInfo_Get
 @pk_ContactInfo = 0    -- int <---THIS IS WHAT I MEAN
```

For example in VS / C#

```
MyClass.UpdateMethod(
  param1: 0,    //int
  param2: "" //string
);
```

I realize that intellisense will show me the parameters, but I'm looking to have a kind of template list of the named argument parameters magically appear to save typing all the named arguments by hand.  For example, start typing the method's name, get to the param list, tab+tab (or some other shortcut magic), have a named argument parameter list show up that I can then update the values for/adjust as needed.

If there isn't a naive VS / intellisense way to do this, can anyone suggest an inexpensive or free plug-in?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. If you are talking about Visual Studio IDE itself then you should be getting the intellisense/auto-complete suggestion when you type in the method name and it should also allow you to auto-complete the method call though you have to actually replace the params with actual input values.

Comment: @adityap - sorry, updated question for clarity.  thanks for response.

Comment: For repetative/custom code you have both [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2017) and [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017) in VS (both native, no plug-in's required).

Answer (score 6):

It works in VS2022.

- 1. step - write method name and hit tab (this will generate all default values for all parameters)

[image]

- 2. step - Hit CTRL + '.' and select "Add argument name"

[image]

- result

[image]